# Как выстроить произвольное количество картинок в один-два ряда?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, imageview

Я делаю ленту новостей, где выводятся посты пользователей. В постах может быть от 1 до 10 картинок. А может вообще не быть ни одной. Задача заключается в том, чтобы вывести эти картинки в один или два ряда (в зависимости от количества). Условия таковы, что если картинок не больше трёх, то они выводятся в один ряд. Если больше, то в первом ряду только две картинки, а во втором остальные. Причём в каждом ряду картинки должны быть одинаковы по высоте, а сам ряд должен быть на всю ширину экрана. Пример того как это будет выглядеть ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне такое реализовать? Мне нужно как-то создавать imageView из кода и считать им размеры и задавать все нужные параметры? Или это возможно реализовать в самом StoryBoard?

В андроиде я делал это приложение и там я сделал так: я в редакторе UI сделал два горизонтальных ряда с ImageView. В первом ряду были 3 imageView, а во втором 8. Все они были деактивированы (GONE), т.е. полностью отключены и имели нулевой размер так сказать. Когда надо было я включал нужное количество (например, два в первом ряду и остальное во втором) и считал размеры на основе ширины экрана по своей формуле, чтобы сумма ширины картинок была равна ширине экрана, а высота была одинакова на основании соотношения сторон каждой картинки.

Какой метод посоветуете для реализации данной задачи под iOS? И желательной объясните так, чтобы было понятно человеку, которые не так давно начал изучать swift.

Также готов услышать и другие варианты компактного отображения группы картинок (например, как в вконтакте)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Советую Вам использовать `UICollectionView` для этого. Вот [урок](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_Swift_iOS_8_Storyboard-based_Collection_View_Tutorial) на Swift. `UICollectionView` позволит Вам создавать динамическое кол-во ячеек(картинок) без необходимости создавать в `UI` много разных `UIImageView` и затем прятать их.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Буду пробовать. 
А можете подсказать, если я загружаю картинки в imageView непосредственно из url это не приведёт к нехватке памяти? 
Я загружаю картинки примерно так как в этом примере:var imgURL:
NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.somewebsite.ru/image.jpg")!
var imgData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL)!
myLovelyImage.image = UIImage(data: imgData)

Comment: Зависит от многих факторов конечно, но лучше сделать кэш например, чтобы при скроллинге не качать картинки каждый раз и не тратить трафик

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Можно также добавлять и динамически. Простой пример под Ваш вопрос:

```
let imgCounter = 7      //количество картинок
let diffTypeCount = 3   //с какого количества делить на 2 ряда
let imagesInFirstRow = 2//количество картинок первого ряда во втором случае
if imgCounter <= diffTypeCount {
    for i in 0..<imgCounter {
        let imgToDisplay = UIImage(named: "AM") //Ваше изображение
        let imgView = UIImageView(frame:
                CGRectMake(0 + CGFloat(i)*self.view.bounds.width/CGFloat(imgCounter),
                0,
                self.view.bounds.width/CGFloat(imgCounter),
                self.view.bounds.width/CGFloat(imgCounter))) //Фрейм скорректировать под нужды

        imgView.image = imgToDisplay
        self.view.addSubview(imgView)
    }
} else {
    for i in 0..<imagesInFirstRow {
        let imgToDisplay = UIImage(named: "AM") //Ваше изображение
        let imgView = UIImageView(frame:
                CGRectMake(0 + CGFloat(i)*self.view.bounds.width/CGFloat(imagesInFirstRow),
                0,
                self.view.bounds.width/CGFloat(imagesInFirstRow),
                self.view.bounds.width/CGFloat(imagesInFirstRow))) //Фрейм скорректировать под нужды

        imgView.image = imgToDisplay
        self.view.addSubview(imgView)
    }
    for i in imagesInFirstRow..<imgCounter {
        let imgToDisplay = UIImage(named: "AM") //Ваше изображение
        let imgView = UIImageView(frame:
                CGRectMake(0 + CGFloat(i - imagesInFirstRow) * self.view.bounds.width/CGFloat(imgCounter - imagesInFirstRow),
                0 + self.view.bounds.width/CGFloat(imagesInFirstRow),
                self.view.bounds.width/CGFloat(imgCounter - imagesInFirstRow),
                self.view.bounds.width/CGFloat(imgCounter - imagesInFirstRow))) //Фрейм скорректировать под нужды

        imgView.image = imgToDisplay
        self.view.addSubview(imgView)
    }
}
```